# Created Dynamic buttons but once i click first button its getting crash

Tags: ios

Created Dynamic buttons but once i click first button its getting crash

```
-(void)dynamicclick:(id)selector
{
  UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)selector;

  btn_tag=(int)btn.tag;

  optionButton = (QBFlatButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:btn_tag];

  optionButton.faceColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:147/255.0 green:192/255.0 blue:31/255.0 alpha:1.0];

  NSLog(@"This is the button with tag: %d", btn_tag);

  [self performSelector:@selector(goMethod:) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5];

  isOptionSelected = YES;
}




-(void)goMethod:(id)selector
{

  if(presentquestion>=AllQuestions.count -1)
  {

    //NSLog(@"---Limit---");

    SummaryVC *summaryVC = [[SummaryVC alloc]init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:summaryVC animated:YES];
  }

  else{

    [self go];
  }

}
```

Comment: Please add more detail. Whats wrong? Where does it crashes?

Comment: In which like your app getting crashed, And Post the method goMethod: code